# Retrieve images from a DB error C# winforms VS2017

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

I have a question please, I'm creating a DB by VS2017 c# winforms, I want to retrieve images from a table but I get an error claiming that "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'"

here is my code;

```
public void FillDGV (string ValueToSearch)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(@"Data Source=WFPIQIRK0H0QKR\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=kurdistan_center; Integrated Security=True");
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("Select * from TBL_costumers", conn);
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    dataGridView1.RowTemplate.Height = 60;
    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    DataGridViewImageColumn ImgCol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    ImgCol = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridView1.Columns[11];
    ImgCol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
    dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
}
```

I'm using MSSQLSERVER Express, any idea ?

Comment: use SqlConnection, SqlCommand, and SqlDataAdapter instead of _MySql_ since you're not using a _MySql_ database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer appreciate it, sure I'm using MySql database, can you please amend the code?

Comment: From your question: "I'm using MSSQLSERVER Express". Note "MS" not "My". MSSQL is Microsoft's SQL server. MySql is an Oracle product. To amend your code, simply remove "My" from the start of "MySqlConnection", "MySqlCommand", and "MySqlDataAdapter".
--- 
If you *are* using MySql, please amend your question.

Comment: You are right, I didn't paid attention, I tried this before and searched everywhere and still stuck in this!

Comment: Can you connect to the database using SQL Management Studio?

Comment: Thank you dear just solved this issue by your cooperation, appreciate it.